# Epigraph / flush right macro for Optex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, optex

Using Optex, I wanted to make a flush right (epigraph) macro/environment.

I tried using e-plain defs for flush left/flush right, but they didn't work.

They should look like this, but this `\hskip 10cm` is kind of clumsy.

[image]

```
\hskip 10cm \vbox{
\bgroup
\parindent 0pt
\_typoscale[800/800]
\it
\obeylines
``Crescem no sul vermelhas sementes,
Vem primavera e poucas vingaram.
Colhe-as, senhor, leva a mão bem cheia;
tantas vicejam como as saudades.''\par
\egroup
}

\bye
```

Two other ways of doing that (`\vbox` isn't needed, and besides, reduces interlinespace):

```
\bgroup
\_typoscale[800/800]
\it
\hfill \table{l}{
“Crescem no sul vermelhas sementes,\cr
Vem primavera e poucas vingaram.\cr
Colhe-as, senhor, leva a mão bem cheia;\cr
tantas vicejam como as saudades.''\cr
}
\egroup


%{\Grey \hrule height 3pt width \hsize}

\bgroup
\leftskip=10cm %\leftskip=.6\hsize
\parindent 0pt
\_typoscale[800/800]
\it
\obeylines
``Crescem no sul vermelhas sementes,
Vem primavera e poucas vingaram.
Colhe-as, senhor, leva a mão bem cheia;
tantas vicejam como as saudades.''\par
\egroup
```

Comment: Did you try with the `epigraph` package?

Comment: @Bernard I somehow doubt that is compatible with the OpTeX-format.

Comment: @Skillmon: I never used this format. I just thought maybe it was worth trying with this package, as its syntax is quite simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that OpTeX provides the macro `\boxlines` which does almost the same like egreg's code `\obeylines\let^^M=\cr\halign{#\hfil`. It puts next lines of source file to individual boxes in vertical mode and the mode is closed by `}`.

```
\noindent {\bf 1 Epigrafe}
\par\nobreak\bigskip
\noindent\hfill\vbox{
   \typoscale[800/800]
   \it
   \boxlines
   \noindent\llap{``}Crescem no sul vermelhas sementes,
   Vem primavera e poucas vingaram.
   Colhe-as, senhor, leva a mão bem cheia;
   tantas vicejam como as saudades.''
}

\bye
```

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that your `\vbox` has horizontal size as wide as the standard `\hsize`, because you're building paragraphs inside it, so you cannot control the actual width of the lines. One could think about dismantling the box and measure each line (which is the last line of a paragraph), but there's a simpler method, namely to use an alignment.

```
\noindent {\bf 1 Epigrafe}
\par\nobreak\bigskip
\noindent\hfill\vbox{
\typoscale[800/800]
\it
\tabskip=0pt
\obeylines\let^^M=\cr\halign{#\hfil
\llap{``}Crescem no sul vermelhas sementes,
Vem primavera e poucas vingaram.
Colhe-as, senhor, leva a mão bem cheia;
tantas vicejam como as saudades.''
}}

\bye
```

[image]